# ORA-12637: Packet receive failed

Tags: oracle

After setting up oracle server, I found I can connect to the oracle by using

```
sqlplus64 user/pass@//192.168.23.14/testsid
```

in server 192.168.23.15

but I can not sqlplus on 172.26.142.33 (my local pc address)

I check the port, actually I can

```
telnet 192.168.23.14 1521
```

Here, I list my server information:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04LTS

```
[oracle@2404f0da2a14 ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 18-JAN-2015 06:25:06

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                18-JAN-2015 04:48:59
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 36 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/2404f0da2a14/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "testsid" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testsid", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "testsidXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testsid", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I also checked sqlnet.ora

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

It seems there is no restriction.

What's the possible problem? Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on dba.stackexchange.com